# Change save path of PHP interactive shell history

Tags: logging, readline, php, interactive-shell

I once found a way to disable session logging by `php -a`, php's interactive shell. How do I turn it back on? Is there a way to send logging to another, file besides `~/.php_history`? I think I may have sent the output to `/dev/null`.

edit: It apparently still saves to the `.php_history` file. It doesn't save until you exit completely from the shell. I would still like to know how move the history logging to another file.

Comment: "session login" or "session logging"?

Comment: It was supposed to be logging :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently (5.3.10 ubuntu) the filename `~/.php_history` is hardcoded in the php source code. Watch :

```
sapi/cli/php_cli.c (line 1127)
```

If you really need the history file in another location you can use a symbolic link. eg :

```
touch /tmp/.php_history
ln -s /tmp/.php_history /home/your_name/.php_history
```

You might also consider sending a feature request to the php developers. They might introduce a php.ini directive for this.