# Clear php-a line history

Tags: php

When i run php -a It brings up a handy shell for testing code quickly along with a history of every line I type. Is there any way to clear this history?

Using php 5.5.9 if this makes any difference

Comment: it will help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768437/change-save-path-of-php-interactive-shell-history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clear history you can use [readline_clear_history()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline-clear-history.php)

```
readline_clear_history ( void );
```

This function clears the entire command line history.

**Return Values**

Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.

Answer (score 8):

On my Linux laptop, there's a `~/.php_history` file that contains the history.

Comment: One can also prevent interactive sessions' history being saved by ensuring that file exists but has read-only permissions.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users, you can find the .php_history file in your home directory as well. I found mine at C:\Users\{my_name}\.php_history